# Grouping a text file by a word in Python (Limited to using lists)

Tags: python, text-files, grouping

I'm new to python and I was wondering how you would group a text file by a single word. For example say my text file looks like this:

```
eggs monday $5 john
bread monday $3 harry
bananas wednesday $2 john
milk saturday $4 sally
tomatoes sunday $7 sally
```

In my case I want to group the file by names. So for John, for example, I want it to be shown like so:

```
[john,[eggs,monday],[bananas,wednesday]]
```

and so on for harry and sally.

So right now my code looks like this and I've been able to identify the necessary things (namely name, item, and day) but I'm confused as to how I can group it.

```
def grocery():
    file = open('shopping.txt')

    wholelist = []
    innerlist = [] 

    for line in file:
        lines = line.split()
        name = lines[3]
        item = lines[0]
        day = lines[1]
```

Thank you in advance. Also I am limited to using a list within a list so I'm not allowed to use dictionaries.

Comment: did you consider using dictionaries instead?

Comment: for the purpose of the assignment that this mini one is based off I was told I have to use lists so for the time being I'm trying to figure how to sort it under those restrictions

Comment: your lecturer needs a lot of coffee

Comment: Please indicate the list restriction in the original question, I think this is why the answers were voted down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this if you have a restriction to use lists only:

```
a ="""eggs monday $5 john
bread monday $3 harry
bananas wednesday $2 john
milk saturday $4 sally
tomatoes sunday $7 sally"""

sents = [b.split() for b in a.splitlines()]
names = []
for s in sents:
    if s[3] not in names:
        names.append(s[3])
        names.append([])

for name in names:
    for s in sents:
        if name == s[3]:
            names[names.index(name)+1].append([s[0], s[1]])

for no in range(0,len(names),2):
    print [names[no]] + [a for a in names[no+1]]
```

Output:

```
['john', ['eggs', 'monday'], ['bananas', 'wednesday']]
['harry', ['bread', 'monday']]
['sally', ['milk', 'saturday'], ['tomatoes', 'sunday']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If not restricted to the usage of lists and dictionaries, I recommend using the [PythoN Data AnalysiS library(pandas)](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for such tabular data with inhomogeneous field types.

It would go something like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data.txt', names=['item', 'day', 'price', 'name'], 
                    delim_whitespace=True)
for name, group in df.groupby('name'):
    print name, ':'
    print group[['item','day']]
```

Output

```
harry :
    item     day
1  bread  monday
john :
      item        day
0     eggs     monday
2  bananas  wednesday
sally :
       item       day
3      milk  saturday
4  tomatoes    sunday
```

If you are restricted to using only lists as you indicated in a comment, I would use the `.index()` method of `list` objects as so:

```
table = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]  # strip the newline char
table = [row for row in table if len(row) > 0]  # remove empty lines
names = []  # for keeping names
groups = [] # for keeping groups associeated to names

for row in table:
    item, day, price, day = row
    try:
        i = names.index(name)
    except ValueError:
        names.append(name)
        i = len(names) - 1
        groups.append([])
    groups[i].append([item, day])

result = list(zip(names, groups))
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
from collections import defaultdict

def grocery():
    wholelist = defaultdict(list)
    with open('shopping.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            lines = line.split()
            wholelist[lines[3]].append(lines[0:2])
    return wholelist

custom_list = [[key]+val for key,val in grocery().items()]
print (sorted(custom_list,key=lambda data:data[0]))
```

`custom_list` has the format you wanted

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('shopping.txt') as file:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for line in file:

        lines = line.split()
        print(lines)
        name = lines[3]
        item = lines[0]
        day = lines[1]
        d[name].append([item, day])
```

out:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'harry': [['bread', 'monday']],
             'john': [['eggs', 'monday'], ['bananas', 'wednesday']],
             'sally': [['milk', 'saturday'], ['tomatoes', 'sunday']]})
```